# Помогите со slice'ом (Python)

Tags: python

[image: уже пробовал все, что можно "x[0:4:2] = [-5, -3, -1]" выдает ошибкуПомогите плз]

уже пробовал все, что можно

```
x[0:4:2] = [-5, -3, -1]
```

выдает ошибку

Помогите плз.

Comment: `x[-1::-2] = [-1, -3, -5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте данный срез (он же slice): 
`x[::2] = [-5,-3,-1]`.
::2 означает заменить каждый второй (начиная с 0 индекса) элемент на элемент в списке. Результат тот который вам нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое